# Is it a good practice to use query to table after select from different table?

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq, query-optimization

I've been wondering if it is a good practice from performance point of view to use following syntax when making call to the table using LINQ. Following is just an example, but I hope you get the idea:

```
Context.Pets.Where(p => p.Name == petname)
            .Select(d => new {
                 SomeProperty = p.Age,
                 SomeOtherProperty = p.Color,
                 VeryDifferentProperty = Context.FavoriteFood.Where(f => f.FavFood == p.FavFood).FirstOrDefault().Nutrition.Protein});
```

Here I'm talking specifically about **VeryDifferentProperty**. Is it OK to make this kind of call?

Comment: Why you don't use [navigation properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships)? Then it would be `VeryDifferentProperty = p.FavoriteFood.Nutrition.Protein`

Comment: It is ok, if you do not have navigation property `Pet -> FavoriteFoods`.

Comment: you could look at find(which should be faster in theory) or move the predicate to firstordefault.  I would try both and benchmark.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of `FavoriteFood` and `Pets` list's size, you might benefit from converting the `FavoriteFood` list to a dictionary (with FavFood as key) to reduce overall execution time.

Currently, processing `Pets` is an `O(n)` operation and calculating value of `VeryDifferentProperty` makes it `O(n^2)`

Depending on number of items in second list, it might be worthwhile to take a one-time hit of converting list to dictionary and then lookups become `O(1)`. There should be no further optimization needed beyond that.